# Maintain indentation in RichTextFX CodeArea

Tags: javafx, richtextfx

I am building a YAML editor in a RichTextFX CodeArea (which I believe is a type of TextArea). I'd like to maintain the current level of indentation when I hit Enter. So for example:

```
- item1: foo
  item1A:
    subElement: A
<there should be 4 spaces here after I hit enter>
```

Alternatively, if somebody already has built a yaml editor in RichTextFX or JavaFX, I'd love a link to it.

When I hit enter after this, to add a subelement unde

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
Pattern whiteSpace = Pattern.compile( "^\\s+" );

codeArea.addEventFilter( KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, KE ->
{
    if ( KE.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER )
    {
        Matcher m = whiteSpace.matcher( codeArea.getParagraph( codeArea.getCurrentParagraph() ).getSegments().get( 0 ) );
        if ( m.find() ) Platform.runLater( () -> codeArea.insertText( codeArea.getCaretPosition(), m.group() ) );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little helper class I wrote that will keep indentation or even increase indentation one level, if the current line ends in a given suffix. It uses the InputMap-API of RichTextFX.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.GenericStyledArea;
import org.fxmisc.wellbehaved.event.EventPattern;
import org.fxmisc.wellbehaved.event.InputMap;
import org.fxmisc.wellbehaved.event.Nodes;  
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;

public class RichTextFXAutoIndenter {
    
    private static final Pattern LEADING_WHITESPACE = Pattern.compile( "^\\s+" );

    public static void install(GenericStyledArea<?, String, ?> genericStyledArea, String ... indentSuffixes) {
        Nodes.addInputMap(genericStyledArea, InputMap.consume(EventPattern.keyPressed(KeyCode.ENTER), event -> enterPressed(genericStyledArea, indentSuffixes)));       
    }
    
    private static void enterPressed(GenericStyledArea<?, String, ?> genericStyledArea, String[] indentSuffixes) {
        genericStyledArea.replaceSelection("\n" + getIndentation(genericStyledArea, indentSuffixes));
    }
    
    private static String getIndentation(GenericStyledArea<?, String, ?> genericStyledArea, String[] indentSuffixes) {
        String currentLine = genericStyledArea.getParagraph(genericStyledArea.getCurrentParagraph()).getSegments().get(0);
        Matcher m = LEADING_WHITESPACE.matcher(currentLine);
        String indent = "";
        if (m.find()) {
            indent =  m.group();
        }
        if (Arrays.stream(indentSuffixes).anyMatch(suffix -> currentLine.trim().endsWith(suffix))) {
            indent += "\t";
        }
        return indent;
    }
}
```

Comment: ```indent = '\t'+indent;``` would be better, if the previous line has spaces at the end to line something up -  You don't want to have spaces before tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a [Turing Machine Simulator](https://github.com/vtramo/advanced-turing-machine-simulator) where the YAML editor serves as the principal tool for composing Turing machine programs. In the context of this project, I faced the same challenge you're currently dealing with, regarding maintaining the indentation level when a new line is added.

```
     private void addKeyPressedEventFilters() {
        codeArea.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,
            keyEvent -> {
                if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    final int currentParagraphIndex = codeArea.getCurrentParagraph();
                    final var currentParagraph = codeArea.getParagraph(currentParagraphIndex);
                    final String currentParagraphText = currentParagraph.getText();

                    final String indentationString = computeIndentationString(currentParagraphText);

                    codeArea.insertText(codeArea.getCaretPosition(), indentationString);
                    codeArea.requestFollowCaret();
                    keyEvent.consume();
                }
            }
        );
    }

    private static String computeIndentationString(final String text) {
        final StringBuilder spacesBuilder = new StringBuilder("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            final char symbol = text.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isSpaceChar(symbol)) {
                spacesBuilder.append(symbol);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return spacesBuilder.toString();
    }
```

This code does the following:

1. It captures the "Enter" key press event;
2. It fetches the current paragraph text from the `CodeArea` element;
3. The method `computeIndentationString` is called to compute a string consisting of an initial newline character (`\n`) and a series of spaces in quantity equal to the number of leading spaces in the current paragraph text;
4. Finally, I call the `codeArea.requestFollowCaret()` method and consume the event with the `keyEvent.consume()` method.

I hope you'll find this helpful.